# toggle div tags with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to toggle div tags with the divs under it (only untill it reaches the div tag with same name)?

```
<div class="div">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>

<div class="div">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>

<div class="div">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
```

and my jQuery doesn't seem to work

```
 jQuery(function() {
 jQuery('.div').click(function() {
    var nextArticle =  jQuery(this).siblings('.job_description.'+jQuery(this))

    if (nextArticle.length) {
        nextArticle.is(':visible') ? nextArticle.slideUp() : nextArticle.slideDown();
    }

    return false;
});
});
```

Thanks

Comment: "toggle" as in "show and hide"?

Comment: do you have control over the html? you can change the markup or classes slightly and make this much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's **[`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)** and **[`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)** to do this in one line:

```
jQuery('.div').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(.job_description)').slideToggle();
});
```

Check demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tgr3nyx4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.div').click(function() {
        var next = $(this).next();

        while (!next.hasClass('div') && next.length > 0)
        {
            next.slideToggle();
            next = next.next();
        }
    });
});
```

[**`jQuery.next()`**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function returns the following sibling in the DOM tree.

By the way, there is a [**`jQuery.slideToggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) function. You don't need to check if it is visible and apply `slideUp` or `slideDown`.

Here is the working [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qgbto6dx/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) on `.div`

```
jQuery(this).nextUntil('.div').slideToggle()
```

Also `slideToggle()` would be better option if you need to toggle the state on subsequent clicks.

```js
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.div').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).nextUntil('.div').slideToggle()
    });
});
```

```css
.job_description{
    display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="div">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="div">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
<div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
```

Why your code does not work?

```
jQuery(this).siblings('.job_description.'+jQuery(this))
```

will result in a selector like

```
jQuery(this).siblings('.job_description.[Object]')
```

as `jQuery(this)` returns an object and not the class name. Also, siblings would give you all the siblings and not just siblings under the current element.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the html markup, I would suggest using a container element and moving your `div` class div into an element that you can use jQuery to exclusively select. Something like:

```js
// use a nested slector in jquery:

$('.container > h1').on('click', function(){
  
  // now just toggle the underlying divs
  // "this" = the h1 within the .container div
  
   var parent = $(this).parent('.container');
   parent.children('.job_description').toggle('slow');
  
});
```

```css
.container > .job_description {
  display : none;
}

.container > h1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Here is more to read.</h1>
  <div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
  <div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
  <div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Here is more to read.</h1>
  <div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
  <div class="job_description">Here is more to read.</div>
</div>
```